# Indicating success/failure within HTTP redirect

Tags: http

I have a web service that takes form submissions and produces a ternary response:

1. Success
2. Server error
3. Client error

The web service and website content are 2 distinct applications and are decoupled.

The web service has no knowledge of the specific content that should be displayed to the client in either 3 states, so instead must rely on redirects to URLs provided by the client as hidden form fields:

```
<form action="http://localhost:8001/submissions" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="email" />
    <input type="hidden" name="success" value="file:///thankyou.html" />
    <input type="hidden" name="client_error" value="file:///client_error.html" />
    <input type="hidden" name="server_error" value="file:///server_error.html" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

The application currently functions with `30*` response codes (i.e. the browser redirects appropriately).

*However,* with my REST hat on, is it possible to return a more meaningful response with `40*` and `50*`, and still have the browser redirect?

I also wish to add some async functionality to the clientside, so this would be particularly useful for determining the request outcome rather than verifying the redirect location against the ones provided, which smells like tunnelling.

Comment: You can have only _one_ HTTP status code in your response. And what does REST have to do with a _direct_ request in the browser? Either you make an API call, _or_ you request a resource directly via address bar to be displayed in the browser. Both at the same time makes little sense to me. (I don’t see why a browser should talk to an API directly.)

Comment: And I also can’t see why the service should _redirect_ in the first place. If there was an error within the scope of the service, then the service should answer with an error directly IMHO (error code/status code, and maybe error message in accompanying response body). I see little sense in having a redirect in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing a standard HTTP POST / HTML Form submit - I would not call this a REST call.

The HTTP Protocol has some predefined [Response Codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Response_codes). If you want any http client (Browser)  to follow the redirects you'll have to use the standard http rediretion status codes i.e. 30x status codes like `302 Found`.

Comment: I would argue this is a REST call - the subject is perhaps a lot broader than you might think. At it's core, REST is simply an advocation for adhering to complementary RFC and W3C standards, with a large focus on HTTP (and thus the correct use of it, i.e. appropriate status codes, predictable behaviour of methods, etc.)

Comment: Independent of whether it can be considered as REST call or even not, redirects for any http clients (browsers) work only if a http status code 30x is returned.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification :) I will continue using 30x